# Android SwipeListView detect button press on backView

Tags: android

Hi i have a SwipeListView which has a backview containing two buttons. The problem i have is that the view is created in my listAdapter so if i put an onClickListener on the buttons it only gets the item thats last in the array. so what i'm trying to do is detect which button has been pressed at in the backview and at what position in the array. Does anyone know how to do this?

heres my layout item xml which has a front and back view as you can see the backview contains two buttons

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

   <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:tag="back"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:text="delete"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_sel"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
       />

          <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/mark_as_read"
            android:text="mark as read"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_sel_rev"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"    
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_read"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"


                /> 


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem"
    android:id="@+id/front"
     >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/pink"
     />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg_date"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/msg_title"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg_title"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/read"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/read"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg_title"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
        android:lines="2" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

in my adapter i am setting an on click listener for the view

```
markAsRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 Log.v("LOG","Array position = " + position);
})};
```

the problem i have with this is although it does detect the click the position is always the last item in the array so if i have 5 items in my array the position no matter which one i click is always 4 and i need it be able to get the posiiton of the item i have clicked  so i can retrieve and edit the data at that position

Comment: Provide some code and XML describing the problem please

Comment: @cYrixmorten i have edited with source code

Comment: Sounds good, just added it as an answer

Comment: i'm facing same problem please share your solution code........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using setTag?

That is, in getView of your adapter issue

```
markAsRead.setTag(TheObjectYouWantToEdit)
```

and then inside the onClick listener

```
TheObjectYouWantToEdit edit = arg0.getTag()
```